# How do I refer to literature in a plural sense?

Tags: sentence-structure, nouns, plural-forms

I know this is similar to another question, but I cannot work from its answer to whether my own sentence is valid.

Is the following sentence correct?

> As this tool is used in many well-cited literature, it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When referring in the aggregate to studies in a particular domain, we say "the literature".

> This tool is well cited in the literature.
>
> This point of view is well represented in the literature.

If a cartographer, say, uses that phrase, the reference is to journal articles relating to cartography. If a biologist uses the phrase, the reference is to journal articles relating to biology, and so on. Its meaning is derived from context.

[Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=2mGC832OcdoC&pg=PA521&dq=%22attested%20in%20the%20literature%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivm-SGlfreAhWGZd8KHRsBBIIQ6AEIdTAN#v=onepage&q=%22attested%20in%20the%20literature%22&f=false)'s just one of many thousands of examples.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> As this tool is used in many well cited ***works of*** literature, it is . . .

Generally speaking, when you use a word that normally take a singular form, but need to express it as a plural, you modify it with something else. (Such as *works of*, *pieces of*, *lengths of*, *examples of*, *bodies of*, and so on.)